# Calculate the limit of $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
I want to determine the limit as formal as possible, that is, to prove, for example
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(k!)}{k}$$
I had the intention of using the L'Hopital rule and I do not know that it does exist, despite only representing a number. But it is not very justified.

Can you use sanduche theorem? Can I limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative by Stolz-Cesaro

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(k!)}{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln((k+1)!)-\ln(k!)}{k+1-k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \log (k+1) =\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for a sequence of positive numbers $a_n$, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})$ exists and equals $L$ ($L$ can be a real number of infinity, it doesn't matter) then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sqrt[n]{a_n})=L$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not considered it.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\log(k!)}k&=\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^k \log(n)\\\\
&=\log(k)+\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^k \log(n/k)\tag1
\end{align}$$

The sum on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is the Riemann sum for the improper integral $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^1 \log(x)\,dx$.

Can you finish this?

Comment: Oh, wow! that great ... is the criterion of the integral and with that I show that it is divergent :) thank you very much !!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Avoiding the problem of why those Riemann sums converge to the improper integral, we could estimate

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\ln j \ge (k/2)\ln (k/2),$$

from which the result follows.

Comment: No concavity needed, just need  $\ln j$ increasing. And I'm doing fine thank you, and I hope the same is true your way.

Comment: I see.  You're using $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$ and $\log(x)$ is increasing.  I missed that upon first glance.